# Selecting with jquery in my own js templating system/engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, template-engine

For simplification and control, I have my own js templating engine, which works like this:

html:

```
 <ul id="persons">
    <li class="person-template hide">
       <span>{name}</span>, <span class="placemark" data-lat="{latitude}" data-lng="{longitude}">{location}</span>
    <li>
 </ul>
```

js:

```
 var persons = [
       {"name":"hulk", "location": "usa", latitude: -33.4, longitude: -70.5}, 
       {"name":"wolverine", "location": "mexico", latitude: -33.4, longitude: -70.5}, 
 ];


 $.each(persons, function(i, person) {
      var html = $(".person-template").clone().removeClass("person-template").addClass("person").show().outerHtml();

      html = html.replaceAll("{name}", person.name);
      html = html.replaceAll("{latitude}", person.latitude);
      html = html.replaceAll("{longitude}", person.longitude);
      html = html.replaceAll("{location}", person.location);
 });
```

(`replaceAll` and `outerHtml` are two helper functions I've made, they are self-explained by their names)

My problem with this is that sometimes I want to select things with jQuery but my template notation interferes, for example:

```
$(".placemark").each(function(i, v) {
     alert($(v).data("latitude")));
});
```

Will alert: "{latitude}", "-33.4", "-33.4"
Obviously I want to avoid the template value.

What is the most clean solution for this?

1. Start using a formal template engine?
2. Skip first in the $.each? (kind of ugly)
3. ...?

Comment: You should clean up your code a bit there so it can be tested and analyzed easier... I think you mean `alert($(v).data("lat");` and `});`  for starters.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I always put simplified code in my questions, and sometimes this happends

Comment: and is $(".location") supposed to be $(".placemark")?  ...and persons is locations? .. anyway, trying to guess what you're getting at, try the solution below if you find the alert is also grabbing the template.

Comment: yes, oh... what an embarrassment, sorry.

Comment: No embarrassment, no sorry, but just trying to be sure. Did you figure it out? If my answer helped, please mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are cloning the template, so it still exists. You need to remove it after you loop through.

```
$(".person-template").remove();
```

or, you can just make sure not to grab the person-template when you alert. $(".location_but_not_location_template").each ...

Comment: ended up using the second suggestion, because removing the template wouldn't let me use it again :)